# Using Large-density Screen Declarations

Tags: android, screen-orientation, samsung-mobile

I am working on an android application and have not yet developed layouts for the `layout-large` orientations of my application. I was wondering if anyone had any details of the types of devices other than a 7 inch tablet that defines this type of screen density. Is this the screen layout that is used for a Note or a Note 2?

Comment: Based on http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html, the Note should be "large", as its 5" screen falls right in the middle of the 4-7" range for large screens. That said, I only have the Note 10", which, of course, reports xlarge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Note / Note 2 are using 320dpi, that is the normal layout for the most phones,
Tablets are using 240dpi or less (192dpi).
But for the most time the layout is automatically resized.

Comment: the density (e.g. 320dpi) is not necessarily related to the device size (e.g. 7").  For example, many older phones have much lower densities, but the screens are still 4".  On the other hand, the Nexus 10 is a 10" (xlarge) tablet, but has a density of 300dpi

Comment: yes, you're right. But even if there is only a little difference in the dpi, there is this second value, the default layout of the device, and in addition to the dpi it resizes the layout in this way, that it looks good, without configuring anything. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should read through Android's [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document.  Especially [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) and [Configuration Examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples).

Basically it comes down to this: unless you know that your users have specific device(s), you really shouldn't try to design to specific devices.  Instead, design to specific sizes in density-independent pixels (e.g. my tablet layout requires a minimum of 600dp in width to be useful).  Then you code your app to change layouts based on some inflection points.

If you're just looking for a general starting point, Google recommends a minimum screen width of 600dp for a 7" tablet and 720dp for a 10" tablet.  Anything less than 600dp becomes a "phone" layout.

Comment: I have read through them, I just had no idea how the note 2 would handle this dictation because the s3 is still considered a normal screen.

Comment: I guess my point was that it shouldn't matter.  Rather than trying to adjust your layout by the size buckets (normal, large, etc.) you should adjust your layout by the actual device size (sw600dp).  It appears that the Note 2 has a 1280x720 pixel screen at hdpi, which would be 853x480 density-independent pixels.